# Switiching Java version per session

Tags: bash, java

I have a combination of Java7 and Java8 installed on my 14.04 machine.

When I want to switch between them I do a `sudo update-alternatives --config java`. However, changing it this way changes the current Java version on all terminals. I wanted to change it only for the current terminal. For example, I want to test some Java code written in 1.7 against other code, compiled in 1.8.

Another alternative would be doing something like

```
function java_use() {
   export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $1)
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   java -version
}
```

But that works only on my Mac and I wanted something cleaner, without having to modify the `PATH` every time. Maybe using `chroot`?

How can I "cleanly" change my Java version - preferably only between the installed versions - and only for the current terminal session?

Comment: There is an excellent blog [post](https://grymoire.wordpress.com/2014/11/20/setting-up-your-linux-environment-to-support-multiple-versions-of-java/) that describes exactly what you are looking for!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at `/usr/sbin/update-java-alternatives`, you'll see it iterates `/usr/lib/jvm/.*.jinfo` to find the installed versions, so you could do the same for detecting the installed versions.

As for not modifying `PATH` every time, you can circumvent `PATH` completely by telling bash which binary it should use for java with the builtin `hash` command (run `help hash`).

Here's something you can build on:

```
java_use() {
    local file version versions=()
    for file in /usr/lib/jvm/.*.jinfo; do
        [[ -e $file ]] || continue
        version=${file##*/.} version=${version%.jinfo}
        versions+=("$version")
    done
    if (( ${#versions[@]} == 0 )); then
        printf >&2 'No java installed\n'
        return 1
    fi
    select version in "${versions[@]}"; do
        if [[ -n $version ]]; then
            export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/$version"
            hash -p "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" java
            break
        fi
    done
    type java
}
```

Comment: awesome. what would be the cherry on top: if it would show which of the versions is currently in use (the same way that `--config java` does), but as it is, it deserves the answer.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos, You could put something like `printf 'Currently using: '; type -P java` at the start of the function

Comment: This is one of the best, most useful answers I've seen at Stack Overflow. Great help, thanks a lot!